# Only two users get the error "...dll has different computed hash than specified in manifest"

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

My WPF app won't start for two new users. It's ClickOnce deployed and runs from the company network (not installed). The error is "**WPF.Themes.dll has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.**" Another dll name appears in the error if I remove WPF.Themes.dll. The error seems accurate when I compare the dll hash to the manifest, so why does the app still run for other users (as it has for 10 years)? It fails on two Win 11 pcs that have the pre-requisite `.Net 4.0 Client` installed (and `.Net 4.0` full). It runs on other Win 11 computers. It is not signed. "`Enable ClickOnce security settings`" is checked/enabled, and when I uncheck that box, Save, and Publish the box is automatically re-checked. I tried changing `Publish->Application Files->Hash` from `Include` to `Exclude` for the DLL but the error still occurs. I have deleted the users cache at `%LocalAppData%\Apps\2.0` and the error still occurs. I've been able to run other WPF applications on the problem PC. This is a real struggle and any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487515/clickonce-signed-application-fails-with-has-a-different-computed-hash-than-spec

Comment: As I stated, the project is not signed, the answers in that link are for a signed assembly.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a real issue with real users unable to launch my application which has run successfully for 10 years. I've worked hours looking for a solution, tried many things, and am seeking help. Please reverse the downvote.