# Error attempting to sign assembly with SHA256 in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I have a XAML browser application created in Visual Studio that I am trying to deploy to a client.  (Using Visual Studio 2015 Community.)

**In attempting to sign my ClickOnce assembly using a commercial certificate (SHA256 algorithm), Visual Studio is giving the following error message:**

> C:\Program Files\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3616,5): error MSB3482: An error occurred while signing: Failed to sign bin\Debug\app.publish\ *[assembly name]* .exe. SignTool Error: Invalid option: /fd

Previously we were using a self-issued test certificate which utilized SHA1 with the following settings:

[image]

But when tried with a self-issued SHA256 test certificate (or using the commercial certificate which is also SHA256) with the following settings we receive the aforementioned error.

[image]

Any ideas on how to get Visual Studio to use these SHA256 certificates?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21844014/signtool-not-signing-clickonce-app-using-sha256-only-uses-sha1

Comment: Do you have familiarity with this issue?  That page has output that the sign tool is successfully running.  I am receiving an error.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using newest version of SignTool? The easiest way to perform the update to the newest version is to go to the Program and Features, select Visual Studio 2015 Community, click Change in the popup window select Modify. Ensure you selected the Selecting ClickOnce Publishing Tools option. After installation retry your operation. [Selecting ClickOnce publishing tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcaPz.png)
[image]

Comment: We ended up having DigiCert re-issue the certificate as SHA1.  Visual Studio absolutely would not play nice with SHA256.  The installation was fresh at the time (May 2016) with the latest version of Visual Studio 2015 Community at that time.  We did not try again after Update 2 or Update 3 came out; perhaps someone could attest as whether or not this was a bug and/or if it was fixed?